# How would I achieve the following XmlSerializer change for my class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I want to produce the following XML:

```
<Base>
    <Child>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
    </Child>
</Base>
```

From the classes:

```
public class Base
{
    public List<Child> children;
    ...elided...
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name;
    ...elided...
}
```

Right now, it's creating:

```
<Base>
    <children>
        <Child>
            <Name>Joe</Name>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <Name>Jack</Name>
        </Child>
    </children>
</Base>
```

How would I change to produce the desired output?

My current code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(base.GetType());
serializer.serialze(stringWriter, base);
return stringWriter.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [XmlElementAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
public class Base
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Child")]
    public List<Child> children;
}
```

... full example ...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xsr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base));

        var b = new Base
        {
            children = new List<Child>
                {
                    new Child { Name= "Joe"},
                    new Child { Name ="Jack"},
                }
        };
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xsr.Serialize(ms, b);

            var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            /*
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <Base xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
              <Child>
                <Name>Joe</Name>
              </Child>
              <Child>
                <Name>Jack</Name>
              </Child>
            </Base>
             */
        }
    }
}

public class Base
{
    [XmlElement("Child")]
    public List<Child> children;
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Just to add on: if there is a need to further promote content from within the list items, the `XmlTextAttribute` can be applied to properties in `Child`, to to serialize as: `<Child>Joe</Child><Child>Jack</Child>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XmlElementAttribute as follows:

```
public class Base
{
    [XmlElement("Child")]
    public List<Child> children;
    ...elided...
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name;
    ...elided...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: The other solutions are better and more direct answers to your question.  However, I'm going to leave this here, as extending List<> rather than including a public List member can be a good idea in some cases.  And it is possible solution.*

Well, you could implement IXmlSerializable, but that might be overkill for what you're looking to do.  Alternately, you could make Base extend List<Child>.

```
public class Base : List<Child>
{
}
```

This will, of course, change how you reference the children in the rest of your code.  If you had base.children[0], you would instead use base[0].

Comment: It's easier than this.